# sync between .gitmodules and .git/config

Tags: git, git-submodules

I added few repositories in .gitmodules by editing the file. Thereafter, I ran the command `git submodule sync` and I could see, that both the files .gitmodules and .git/config are in sync. However, I still dont see the added respositores when I run `git submodule status`

What could be wrong here?

Comment: `git submodule sync` copies the data but doesn't clone the new submodules. You'll need to use `git submodule update` to make it run `git clone`.

Comment: Yes, but the update would only be done on the submodules that are listed in git submodule status. My problem is that, the modules that I added manually in .gitmodules does not appear in git submodule status.

Comment: Ah, right: the `git submodule` script uses the `git-submodule--helper` program to scan Git's index for gitlink entries, and they won't exist at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that just adding the name in the .gitmodules or .git/config does not make the submodule also available automatically.

You have to execute the command git submodule add   in order to index the submodule.

`git submodule status` just shows the content of the indexed entries and not the entries avaiable in .gitmodules or .git/config